# Is there a function similar to get_queried_object() that only gets the current archive taxonomy term but IGNORES url query parameters?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

Currently I have a taxonomy page using a custom php archive template. I am using ACF fields and needed to use the get_queried_object() to get the current taxonomy term/ID so that I could use taxonomy related custom fields.

My issue is I also have a search set up on the page that uses some url query parameters. And when I use the query parameters it interferes with the get_queried_object(), and takes the first url query parameter value. So my get_queried_object() is querying the url parameter and not the taxonomy's archive page that it is on.

I don't want to put my whole code in here, as a lot of it is unrelated, so I'll just put one small part of it.

```
<?php
$taxterm = get_queried_object();
$background_image = get_field('background_banner_image', $taxterm);
?>

<div class="page-header page-header_align_center" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $background_image['url'];  ?>)">
  <h2><?php the_field('heading', $taxterm); ?></h2>
  <?php the_field('intro_text', $taxterm); ?>
</div>
```

I've potentially overlooked something obvious, but is there a different WP function that gets the current archive's taxonomy term/id?

**EDIT:**
My var_dump($taxterm) results with no url parameter:

```
  public 'term_id' => int 50
  public 'name' => string 'All Home Designs' (length=16)
  public 'slug' => string 'all' (length=3)
  public 'term_group' => int 0
  public 'term_taxonomy_id' => int 50
  public 'taxonomy' => string 'level-type' (length=10)
  public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'parent' => int 0
  public 'count' => int 2
  public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
```

With url parameter of ?series=classic

```
  public 'term_id' => int 51
  public 'name' => string 'Classic Series' (length=14)
  public 'slug' => string 'classic' (length=7)
  public 'term_group' => int 0
  public 'term_taxonomy_id' => int 51
  public 'taxonomy' => string 'series' (length=6)
  public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'parent' => int 0
  public 'count' => int 1
  public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
```

Comment: Can you show some examples on what is returned when you `var_dump($taxterm)` with and without query parameters? because in my understanding, there shouldn't be any issues there

Comment: @Stender I have edited my question to include what is returned for var_dump($taxterm)

Answer (score 0):

While you on you term archive page, queried object should represent term object. if not - probalby you doing something wrong.

If you using ?s parameter in you search form, just change it, coz it reserved by wordpress and recognizing as search.

Anyway, instead of using `get_queried_object` or `get_queried_object_id` you can check global query, there is should be what you looking for

```
global $wp_query;
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);
```

Comment: Hey, I added the above to my code, and I get the same issue as before ... I have edited my question to include what is returned from var_dump($taxterm) with and without url parameters. I tested it with yours above and get the same (except more information within the array)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully explored the ins and outs of why this is happening, but had a similar issue when using taxonomy.php combined with query vars relating to taxonomies in the URL, and solved it by checking the request against the query:

```
global $wp;
global $wp_query;

$queried_object = get_queried_object();

// Grab what should be the term slug from the request
$req_path_last = basename($wp->request);

// If the term doesn't match the slug from the request, and the request slug exists as a term, attempt to use the right one
if (isset($queried_object->slug)
    && $queried_object->slug !== $req_path_last
    && term_exists($req_path_last)
    && is_array($wp_query->query)) {

    // If the term slug has been queried, either as a string or string in an array, let's grab the tax slug (should be the key)
    foreach ($wp_query->query as $slug => $value) {
        if ($value === $req_path_last || (is_array($value) && in_array($req_path_last, $value))) {
            $tax_slug = $slug;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If we have a taxonomy slug, use it, otherwise grab all potential terms based on the URL slug and use the first one
    if (!empty($tax_slug)) {
        $new_queried_object = get_term_by('slug', $req_path_last, $tax_slug);
    } else {
        $potential_terms = get_terms([
            'slug' => $req_path_last,
        ]);

        $new_queried_object = count($potential_terms) > 0 ? $potential_terms[0] : null;
    }

    $queried_object = $new_queried_object instanceof WP_Term ? $new_queried_object : $queried_object;
}
```